# Kivy call function in other screen

Tags: python, function, class, oop, kivy

So I'm working on a kivy project and also learning the language for it (I mean python) and I have this little program here. So there are some language button on my first screen but I also have text to change in the second page. How can I call an other class' function in a class, or should I use a different way to change the textes? Any tipp would be helpful :) thanks

```
class ScreenOne(Screen):
   def d_language(self):
      self.hellolabel.text='Hallo'
   def fr_language(self):
      self.hellolabel.text='Bonjour'

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
   def d_languagetwo(self):
      self.otherlabel.text='Zweite seite'
   def fr_languagetwo(self):
      self.otherlabel.text='Deuxième page'
```

Comment: Hi Levi, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024151/calling-function-in-a-different-class-through-kivy-button/45025220#45025220) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965114/calling-a-function-from-class-in-python-different-way). Also, where is your Button? if possible add more code of your project

Comment: thanks for the tipps :) Yoav Glazner's answer was the main thing I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the screen manager to get to the other screen

```
def d_language(self):
    self.hellolabel.text = 'Hallo'
    #now change the other label
    s2 = self.manager.get_screen('name of the other screen')
    #or ...
    #s2 = self.manager.screens[1] # will also work...
    s2.otherlabel.text = 'Zweite seite' 
    #or ...
    #s2.d_languagetwo()
```

...

Comment: Thank you so much. I hoped there is something like this but i couldn't find anything on web